# Equation of line normal to $y = x^3 -2x^2$ at $x=0$

Tags: derivatives

- Find the equation of normal to the curve $y =x^3 - 2x^2$ at $x= 0.$
- Find the co-ordinates of the point of intersection of the normal and
  the line $y = 4.$

I differentiated the equation with respect $x$ and I got: $dy/dx=3x^2-4x$. But the slope of normal should be a non-zero, finite term right? I just don't know how to proceed further with this. I tried double-differentiating it but I'm pretty sure that's not the correct method.

Comment: Normal can be vertical

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 2):

Well, sort of.

Slope can indeed be zero: that signifies that the line tangent to the curve at $x=0$, after evaluating $dy/dx$ at $0$ gives $\dfrac{dy}{dx}= 0$.

When slope equals zero, we know we have a horizontal line tangent at $x=0$, in this case. That horizontal line is given by $y(0) = 0$.

Since the line tangent at $0$ is horizontal, the normal at $x = 0$ will be a vertical line (slope is undefined), indeed, it is given by the line $x=0

The point of intersection between $x=0$ and $y = 4$ is precisely $(0, 4)$.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the derivative, you have the slope of the tangent line. You know that the normal must be perpendicular to this tangent line.

If you have a slope of $0$ for your tangent line, what's the slope (crudely speaking) of your normal? A negative reciprocal... which is more or less an infinitely steep line; that is, a straight vertical line. Thus, the solution is $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

The first helper to you is the plot of this function:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y+%3Dx%5E3+-+2x%5E2

So you can easily see that the normal is vertical in the $x=0$. So the intersection with the line $y=4$ comes at the point $(0,4)$.